# Wait until one element in list disappears

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table in which every row has a column with a checkbox. In case I uncheck it, it hides the row. I want to wait until this row disappears.

The things I've found are for when I have a concrete locator with `EC.invisibility_of_element_located`, but in this case, since are rows, every row has the same class and it doesn't make any sense to put an id to every row.

I would like to avoid something like `time.sleep(2)`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait until the list count decreased by 1:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr')
list_count = len(_list)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr')) == list_count - 1)
```

This should work if row is physically deleted from DOM. In case it becomes hidden use something like `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[not(@hidden)]')` to locate visible rows